# Google Cloud Messaging after changing package name

Tags: android

If I change the package name of an application associated with Google Cloud Messaging (for example push notifications) Was this service disabled from this app?

Comment: Hi fachka, you seem to have forgotten to finish your first sentence. "If I change the package name, *then something should happen here* - the italicized bit seems to be missing. Can you edit your question to include all the information?

Comment: Yes it is disabled!

Comment: it is disabled without changing any ids or someting ?